# Using Multiple WHERE clause in an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

Am having two tables inside my Database lets say Table1 and Table2, and am trying to copy the values from a specific rows(fields) in Table2 to a specific single row on Table1, The specific rows to be moved are determined by the User Input of Particular UserID of each row from Table1.

Table Structure:

```
 Table 1:        a_uid,a_FName,a_Username,a_PhoneNo,b_uid,b_FName,b_Username,b_PhoneNo......
```

And Table 2 Structure:

```
Table 2: uid,FName,Username,PhoneNo.....
```

Am uing the INSERT INTO .. SELECT statement, but with multiple WHERE clause but its giving me erros

```
INSERT INTO table1 WHERE uid='userinput1' (b_FName,b_Username,b_PhoneNo,) SELECT  FName,Username,PhoneNo FROM table2 WHERE uid='userinput2';
```

But am getting Error

> ### This type of clause was previously parsed. (near WHERE)

Comment: you can't put where condition in insert.

Comment: if you already have row with uid then you have to update it.

Comment: Why don't you just `ALTER TABLE` to change the column names.
`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN old_name TO new_name;`

Comment: which RDBMS are you using, mysql or mssql? those are two different animals

Comment: and why was this tagged as php?

Comment: RTM on `INSERT ... SELECT` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I removed the redundant tags. Edit your question using the tags according to the RDBMS used. mysql and sql-server are two different RDBMS'

Comment: Am working with MySQL not sql-server, and am using PHP as my scripting language, just added that so anyone could understand

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the Response, thou I just edited the Question, Want I intend to achieve is to copy some of the values from the specific row in Table 2 to a specific row in Table 1, the specific Row in Table 1 already has some column partially filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row in `table1` already exists, you need an `UPDATE .. JOIN` statement instead of `INSERT .. SELECT`.

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.uid='userinput2'
SET t1.b_FName    = t2.FName,
    t1.b_Username = t2.Username,
    t1.b_PhoneNo  = t2.PhoneNo 
WHERE t1.uid='userinput1'
```

If you don't know if the row in `table1` already exists, you can use an `INSERT .. SELECT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (uid, b_FName, b_Username, b_PhoneNo)
    SELECT 'userinput1', FName, Username, PhoneNo
    FROM table2
    WHERE uid = 'userinput2'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    SET b_FName    = VALUES(FName),
        b_Username = VALUES(Username),
        b_PhoneNo  = VALUES(PhoneNo)
```

Note that `uid` sould be primary keys or at least unique in both tables.

Comment: I deleted the CROSS clause as it was giving me error, But using it without the cross clause worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Hmm.. It's possible that a CROSS JOIN is not allowed in an UPDATE statement (Even though the [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) states: "In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents"). But since I don't like to see a JOIN without an ON clause, I moved the `userinput2` condition to the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

For sql-server it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (uid,FName,Username,PhoneNo) 
SELECT @userinput1, FName,Username,PhoneNo 
FROM table2 
WHERE table2.uid=@userinput2;
```